WebSocket Connection Refused with HTTP 403 Error in Python Script - dexscreener
I'm encountering an issue while trying to establish a WebSocket connection using Python. Despite following the standard procedure for setting up the connection, the server keeps rejecting it with an HTTP 403 error. I've provided the relevant details below, including my script and the WebSocket connection parameters.

import asyncio
import websockets
import os
import base64
import json

def generate_sec_websocket_key():
    random_bytes = os.urandom(16)
    key = base64.b64encode(random_bytes).decode('utf-8')
    return key

async def dexscreener_scraper():
    headers = {
        "Host": "io.dexscreener.com",
        "Connection": "Upgrade",
        "Pragma": "no-cache",
        "Cache-Control": "no-cache",
        "User-Agent": "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_15_7) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/122.0.0.0 Safari/537.36",
        "Upgrade": "websocket",
        "Origin": "https://dexscreener.com",
        "Sec-WebSocket-Version": "13",
        "Sec-WebSocket-Key": generate_sec_websocket_key(),
        "Accept-Encoding": "gzip, deflate, br, zstd",
        "Accept-Language": "fr-FR,fr;q=0.9,en-US;q=0.8,en;q=0.7"
    }
    uri = "wss://io.dexscreener.com/dex/screener/pair/solana/zcdaw3jpcqey8jyvxnvmqs2cu35cyddy4ot7v8ednhz"
    async with websockets.connect(uri, extra_headers=headers) as websocket:
        while True:
            message_raw = await websocket.recv()
            message = json.loads(message_raw)
            print(message)
            await asyncio.sleep(1)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    asyncio.run(dexscreener_scraper())

Error :
websockets.exceptions.InvalidStatusCode: server rejected WebSocket connection: HTTP 403

Additional Information:
Below is the WebSocket connection information from my browser's developer tools:
Request URL: wss://io.dexscreener.com/dex/screener/pair/solana/zcdaw3jpcqey8jyvxnvmqs2cu35cyddy4ot7v8ednhz
Request Method: GET
webpage : https://dexscreener.com/solana/zcdaw3jpcqey8jyvxnvmqs2cu35cyddy4ot7v8ednhz

Request Headers:
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate, br, zstd
Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.9,ar;q=0.8
Cache-Control: no-cache
Connection: Upgrade
Host: io.dexscreener.com
Origin: https://dexscreener.com
Pragma: no-cache
Sec-WebSocket-Extensions: permessage-deflate; client_max_window_bits
Sec-WebSocket-Key: Qth1VxWMPWjj5C+s5z4qQA==
Sec-WebSocket-Version: 13
Upgrade: websocket
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/126.0.0.0 Safari/537.36

Any insights or suggestions on how to resolve this issue would be greatly appreciated.
Thank you in advance for your help!

Did you end up resolving this issue? I'm facing the same thing. Initially I thought it was due to a new header being added to the request (Sec-Websocket-Extensions) but adding this to my request didn't seem to work either.

No, unfortunately, I haven't succeeded. The code works perfectly on my second PC but not on the first one (it used to work on both). I've tried several things, but it still doesn't work. I'm using the same Python version, the same packages, and the same Windows security settings...

I ran into the same problem with the DexScreener WebSockets. It seems like they were able to be consumed publicly before (probably an oversight on their end), but now it is secured by CloudFlare and the WebSockets no longer work.
